# how to update image in view in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am designing an image and doing saving.The image is first time binding in view.When am redesigning the same
image and saving again.But view is not updating.

```
$scope.$on('Save', function () {
                vm.save();
                if (vm.scenarioStoryBoardData.ScenarioStoryBoard.isDesigner) {
                    var file = vm.DrawStateService.getBlob();
                    file.name = vm.parentScenario.replace(" ", "") + "_scenario_storyboard.png";
                    Upload.upload({
                        url: BodStudioServicesEndpoint + "TechnologyStoryboardImage/Upload?UserId=" + LoggedInUserGUID,
                        method: "POST",
                        data: { file: file },
                        cache: false
                    }).then(function (resp) {                            
                        vm.scenarioStoryBoardData.ScenarioStoryBoard.ImgSrc = resp.data;
                        $scope.$parent.studio.saveBodData();
                    }, function (resp) {
                        console.log('Error');
                    }, function (evt) {
                        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    });
                }
                else
                    $scope.$parent.studio.saveBodData();
            });

 <img ng-click="scenarioStoryboard.importGallery();scenarioStoryboard.currParentIndex = -1;scenarioStoryboard.isAllowToDelete = true;" class="img-responsive" ng-if="scenarioStoryboard.scenarioStoryBoardData.ScenarioStoryBoard.ImgSrc" ng-src="{{scenarioStoryboard.imagesUrl}}{{scenarioStoryboard.scenarioStoryBoardData.ScenarioStoryBoard.ImgSrc}}" />
```

Comment: does the url in ng-src contains the new image url?

Comment: no same url am getting

Comment: ng-src should be new image url!

Comment: am redesigning the  same image so url cannot be changed

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for your problem!

Comment: url is same i need to update the view

Comment: How about using '$apply'?